Next Js dynamic API route doesn't receive [SLUG]
I'm trying to fetch an API route which is in
/api/show/[id].js

with following code
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

import {
  client,
  connectToMongoDB,
  closeMongoDBConnection,
} from "@/utils/mongo";

export default async function handler(req,res) {
  const { id } = req.query;
  return NextResponse.json({id : id})
} 

My client component function to get the post with a certain id
useEffect(() => {
  const getPost = async () => {
    // Make the function async
    const url = "/api/post?id=" + param.id;
    console.log(url);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, { method: "GET" });
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
  getPost();
}, [param.id]);

I tried to fetch this url in my client component or Thunder client but it throws an error, on this line:
Thunder client response ={ 


Status: 404 Not Found

In fetch it says method not allowed. The route is not accessible in the browser
I tried to use nested API routes, because I already have some endpoints but it didn't work. API endpoints works when not using the slug.
